# Loading different components in one component - reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am creating a 4 steps form in reactjs.

Main components is loading sub-components inside it.

When user fill one form and press continue, it should save values of form 1 and load form2 in place of form one. How would i achieve it.

Form 1

```
handleClick() { //When user submits form 1
    //Save All Values of form 1 and load form 2 


    //window.openAppRoute("/payments"); //Not Working
    //hashHistory.push('/dashboard'); //Not Working
    //history.push('/dashboard'); //Not Working
}
```

Main component:

```
return (
  <div className="custom-container">

    <div className="page-content">
        <Form1 />
        //<Form2 /> Should load next
        //<Form3 /> Should load next
    </div>
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways you could do this. Either create each component inside your container App component and have a state variable control which step should be shown, or create sub-routes that link to each other.

Example of first approach:

```js
class MyApp extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      step: 0
    };
  }
  
  nextStep = () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({step: prevState.step + 1}));
  }
 
  render() {
    let {step} = this.state;
    let form = [<Form1 />, <Form2 />, <Form3 />];
    return(
      <div>
        {form[step]}
        {form.length-1 > step && <button onClick={this.nextStep}>Next</button>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Form1 = () => <div>Form 1</div>;
const Form2 = () => <div>Form 2</div>;
const Form3 = () => <div>Form 3</div>;
 
ReactDOM.render(<MyApp />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to keep form data on the main component and handle changes with event handlers

Given your example:

```
const { data, step } = this.props

return (
  <div>
    {step === 0 && <Form1 data={data} onChange={/**/} />}
    {step === 1 && <Form2 data={data} onChange={/**/} />}
    {step === 2 && <Form3 data={data} onChange={/**/} />}
  </div>
)
```

Whenever a change is triggered, you have control over `data` to make the appropriate changes and later
dispatch them to your redux store, state, backend api...

Comment: but this is loading all three forms at once right? i want to load forms one by one.